# get file type of request.files in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

How to get file extension from the request.files collection in asp.net?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile file in Request.Files) {
    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Each `HttpPostedFile` in `Request.Files` has a `FileName` that includes the extension; to get **just** the extension, use `Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)`

Note that using the content-type may be more reliable in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

Request.Files is actually a Name Object Collection so this code would work better

```
foreach (string keyName in Request.Files) {
    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[keyName].FileName);
}
```

and this code worked for me.